# String cells data is not visible in excel editor when excel is created using SXSSFWorkbook and modified using XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, libreoffice

**Scenario:**
1) A csv file is converted into excel file using SXSSFWorkbook.
2) If the data is again read from CSV file and written to the above generated excel file using XSSFWorkbook then the string data is not visible in libre office but data is visible if the excel file is opened in online excel viewer(some of the excel viewers are mentioning that the file is corrupt and data can be recoverable).

Cell creation Using SXSSFWorkbook:
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Some Value");

Cell updation using XSSFWorkbook:
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Some Value");

**Observations:**
1) When cell value is updated using XSSFCell, then the raw value of cell and string value of the cell are different.

2) If excel file is generated with SXSSFWorkbook and opened using XSSFWorkbook then internally maintained STCellType is STCellType.INLINE_STR and if excel file is generated using XSSFWorkbook then internally maintained STCellType is STCellType.S (STCellType is used in CTCell of XSSFCell).

Apache POI Version: 4.1.0

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SXSSFWorkbook` uses inline strings per default while `XSSFWorkbook` uses shared strings table per default. And [XSSFCell.setCellValueImpl](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java?view=markup#l401) is incomplete for inline strings. It does:

```
...
if(_cell.getT() == STCellType.INLINE_STR) {
 //set the 'pre-evaluated result
 _cell.setV(str.getString());
}
...
```

So for inline strings it always sets `v` element containing the text. But inline strings also may have `is` element having `t` element containing the text, or even `is` element having different rich text runs. This is not considered using `XSSFCell`.

But [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) can be constructed so it also uses shared strings table. See constructor `SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook, int rowAccessWindowSize, boolean compressTmpFiles, boolean useSharedStringsTable)`. So if following constructor used:

```
SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 2, true, true);
```

then no inline strings are used and later updating using `XSSF` will not be problematic.

---

If `SXSSFWorkbook` is not using shared strings table but inline strings, there is a problem when later updating cells using `XSSF` because of the incompleteness of `XSSFCell` in using inline strings. Possible workaround will be managing the inline strings updating with own code.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellType;

public class SXSSFTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // first create SXSSFTest.xlsx using SXSSF ============================================

  String[][] data1 = new String[][]{
   new String[]{"A1", "B1", "C1"},
   new String[]{"A2", "B2", "C2"},
   new String[]{"A3", "B3", "C3"},
   new String[]{"A4", "B4", "C4"}
  };

  SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
  //SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 2, true, true);

  SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet();

  int r = 0;
  for (String[] rowValues : data1) {
   SXSSFRow row = sxssfSheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String value : rowValues) {
    SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c++);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("SXSSFTest.xlsx");
  sxssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
  outputStream.close();
  sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
  sxssfWorkbook.close();

  // now reread the SXSSFTest.xlsx and update it using XSSF =============================

  String[][] data2 = new String[][]{
   new String[]{"A2 New", "B2 New", "C2 New"},
   new String[]{"A3 New", "B3 New", "C3 New"}
  };

  XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(
                               new FileInputStream("SXSSFTest.xlsx"));

  XSSFSheet xssfSheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

  r = 1;
  for (String[] rowValues : data2) {
   XSSFRow row = xssfSheet.getRow(r++); if (row == null) row = xssfSheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String value : rowValues) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c++); 
    if (cell != null) { // cell was already there
     if (cell.getCTCell().getT() == STCellType.INLINE_STR) { // cell has inline string in it
      if (cell.getCTCell().isSetIs()) { // inline string has is element
       cell.getCTCell().getIs().setT(value); // set t element in is element
      } else {
       cell.getCTCell().setV(value); // set v element of inline string
      }
     } else {
      cell.setCellValue(value); // set shared string cell value
     }
    } else {
     cell = row.createCell(c++);
     cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
   }
  }

  outputStream = new FileOutputStream("XSSFTest.xlsx");
  xssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
  outputStream.close();   
  xssfWorkbook.close();

 }
}
```

After that the `SXSSFTest.xlsx` looks like so in my `LibreOffice Calc`:

[image]

All cells have inline strings in it.

And the `XSSFTest.xlsx` looks like so:

[image]

There all inline strings are updated correctly now.

```
LibreOffice
Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5
```

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you for response.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you for response. If rows and cells are again created using xssfworkbook, then the data is visible in libre office. But, my issue is that the rows and cells should not be created, instead they have to be read from the xssfworkbook itself. The issue will be reproduced if "XSSFRow row = xssfSheet.createRow(r++);" is replaced with "XSSFRow row = xssfSheet.getRow(r++);" and "XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c++);" is replaced with "XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c++);"

Comment: @Anand Kumar: I see the problem now. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter, Thanks for the reply. Both the solutions provided above have resolved the issue. I am going to proceed with the first solution